# "db init" with postgres for Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am referencing to [this doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html) and [this article](https://newt-tan.medium.com/apache-airflow-installation-based-on-postgresql-database-26549b154d8) in linking a Postgres database to Airflow.

Particularly, I added this line to the file `airflow.cfg`:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflowadmin:airflowadmin@localhost/airflowdb
```

where `airflowadmin` is both the username and password for the postgres user and password, and `airflowdb` is a postgres db created, with `airflowadmin` having all the privileges.

Now, when I initialize the database with `airflow db init`, however, I still see `sqlite` being the linked database. Full output:

```
DB: sqlite:////home/userxxxx/airflow/airflow.db
[2021-09-07 12:43:53,827] {db.py:702} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
WARNI [airflow.models.crypto] empty cryptography key - values will not be stored encrypted.
WARNI [unusual_prefix_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_example_kubernetes_executor_config] Could not import DAGs in example_kubernetes_executor_config.py: No module named 'kubernetes'
WARNI [unusual_prefix_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_example_kubernetes_executor_config] Install kubernetes dependencies with: pip install apache-airflow['cncf.kubernetes']
Initialization done
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `airflow.cfg` file you are changing is the same that is actually being loaded by Airflow. From the CLI run:

`airflow info`

Search under the **Paths info**  section and compare it with the path of the folder with the `airflow.cfg` file that you are modifying.

airflow info:

```
ache Airflow
version                | 2.1.2                                              
executor               | SequentialExecutor                                 
task_logging_handler   | airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler
sql_alchemy_conn       | sqlite:////home/vagrant/airflow/airflow.db         
dags_folder            | /home/vagrant/airflow/dags                         
plugins_folder         | /home/vagrant/airflow/plugins                      
base_log_folder        | /home/vagrant/airflow/logs                         
remote_base_log_folder |        

                                                                          
System info
OS         
...
...
                            
Paths info
airflow_home    | /home/vagrant/airflow
...
```

When not defined during the [local installation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html#running-airflow-locally) process, the default value of `airflow_home`is `AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`, so I guess that may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. you are right. I installed Airflow twice: once on local, once in a pipenv virtual. The local one runs on Sqlite. The pipenv, I am trying to link to postgres. But it still point to the ```airflow_home``` of the local airflow.